# Meaning of 'to gain acceptance for something'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"Gain Acceptance for Your Ideas in 6 Steps" is the title of a webpage. The meaning is clear. It's about some techniques you can use to persuade others to accept your ideas in workplace, a company, etc. But here is another example from a different source:

> But the ideas are, in the main, derived from Anarchism, and **the men who gained acceptance for them were, for the most part, Anarchists.**

How does a native English speaker understand the emphasized sentence?

1. The ideas were accepted by Anarchists more than by any other group of people.
2. We can't infer from this sentence what group accepted the ideas more than other groups. It just says that Anarchists were the group who publicized and popularized the ideas most successfully.

Comment: Number two is the right answer.

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer *acceptance **of** [the ideas.]* To me, using ***for*** there ascribes an inappropriate level of "volition, purpose, ambition" to the ideas (it's almost "anthropomorphic" to make the ideas a "beneficiary" like that). I suspect the writer might have used ***of*** if he didn't *endorse* those ideas himself.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, the sentence was written by Bertrand Russell in 1918.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, And Russell advocated some versions of socialism and anarchism at that time.

Comment: It might be interesting to know if Russell ever used *...acceptance **of / for** [ideas]* anywhere else in his writing, to see whether he ever implemented the distinction I raised. But [here's the evidence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=acceptance+of+the+idea%2Cacceptance+for+the+idea&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) that as a general principle, we refer to *acceptance **of** ideas*, not ***...for** ideas*.